# Why Does Chrome show color but not Firefox? (CSS)

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox

So im designing a webpage but the table color inside does not show up in Chrome when it shows up in Firefox.

I really have no idea how this is! Here is what im talking about:
[image]
([Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U6HNO.jpg) for larger image)

Here is my css source:
http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=hnNkwkGX

Can someone resolve this or explain to be the problem?
Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried using an online gradient generator? And check the code it generates and compare it to yours? Also, you should always include the standard version without the prefixes.

Answer (score 2):

Firefox does not operate via the `-webkit` renderings and such. You'll have to add a `-moz-linear-gradient` for your gradients as well as your already-existing `-webkit-linear-gradient`.

Comment: -1 He added `-moz-linear-gradient`, in fact.

Comment: Not on his `form` element, which is the piece that isn't getting styled correctly in Firefox.

Comment: You're right, my eyes failed me ;). I can't remove the downvote though, if you edit your answer, I could.